# Security access to a table

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a database and table dbo.Test_Table, with list of Users under Security -> Users. those users have access to all the tables in my database.

I would like to know how do I assign certain users to specific tables (e.g dbo.Test_Table) within the database, that only those Users can view those tables within my database.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view and assign only some users to access that view.

BTW, please correct your tags you added MS-SQL and MySQL